# How can i automatically close a program after testrunning via ant?

Tags: java, ant

the title says what i'm trying to do. I am really new to ant and automated build-processes, please take that into consideration. The program is a simple digital watch and it executes just fine via ant. The next thing i wanted to do is getting rid of the need to manually close the running program via GUI-interaction.

My build-file looks like this, if that helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="ue8a3" basedir="." default="main">
    <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.dir" value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
    <property name="main-class" value="DigitalWatch"/>  
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="generateJar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
    </target>
    <target name="execute" depends="compile , generateJar">
        <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/>
    </target>
    <target name="main" depends="clean, execute"/>
</project>
```

Comment: Can it be based on a timeout?  The [java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) has a `timeout` parameter.

Comment: Works for me! Thanks for your answer :) If someone feels there is something more best-practice-like available i would appreciate if it's mentioned.

Comment: I just recognized that ant will report an error in this solution. It does what it's supposed to do but for ant the timeout seems to be a safety measure to kill a process which doesn't work as expected. Any suggestions for a "cleaner" way to do this?

Comment: You may have success wrapping your `<java>` task in a [`<parallel>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html) task, which has its own timeout parameter and which (I think) doesn’t fail if the timeout is reached.

Comment: Generates 3 errors :/

Comment: It works for me.  Set the `timeout` parameter of the `java` task, not the `parallel` task.

Comment: Hm...mysterious; did that which reduced it back to generating one error. Are you giving the parallel tag any other arguments?

Comment: Nope.  Just `<parallel><java fork="true" classname="Test" classpath="." timeout="5000"/></parallel>` (formatted a little better than that, of course).

Comment: Not working for me...i'm executing from a *.jar though but i would find it rather odd if that would have something to to with it...i try to remember to report back if i know a way how to get rid of this.

Comment: Another solution on that but i'm not completely satisfied with that:
use a special constructor which will terminate the program after a given time and let ant make use of this constructor by passing certain args. Works...but i don't like it that the class get's an otherwise unneeded constructor.